# forfiles to lookup folders and put the info in a text file

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to use forfiles to lookup folders and put the info in a text file, the folders need to start with a specific character and have a specific date (age).

I tried this:

```
forfiles /m f* /d -10 /c "cmd /c if @isdir == TRUE >folders.txt"
```

But then I get a syntax error.

So I tried this:

```
forfiles /m f* /d -10 /c "cmd /c if @isdir == TRUE echo @isdir"
```

Now I am getting the value TRUE

I do not know if it is possible what I want with forfiles or if I need a different command.

Any help would be nice,
Dave

Comment: You are not redirecting any output stream to folders.txt.  You need to echo the file or folder it found to folders.txt. I don't see any difference in your two code examples.

Comment: surely you should be `echo`ing `@path`, `@file` or `@fname`, `echo`ing `@isdir` correctly `echo`es the result, "if @isdir equals TRUE echo @isdir" is the same as "if @isdir equals TRUE echo TRUE".

Comment: Thanks for the help, "@file" or "@fname" is what I need. Also my mistake I should have used echo to text